# Infinite computably enumerable set is the image of a computable $1:1$ function

Tags: logic, algorithms, solution-verification, recursion, computability

I'm trying to prove this fact:

> A set $A$ is computable enumerable (c.e.) iff it is either empty or is the image of a total computable function. Moreover, if $A$ is infinite, the function can be taken to be 1:1.

Does this proof look correct?

Suppose $A$ is infinite. $A$ is c.e., so there is a program (enumerator) such that if we run it (with no input), it would spit out all elements of $A$. Define the function $f:N\to N$ by $n\mapsto n\text{th element that the enumerator spits out}$. This function is computable by the following program: it accepts $n$, launches the enumerator, waits until it spits out the $n$th element and outputs the $n$th element. Also, $f$ is total since $A$ is infinite (I guess the above doesn't work for finite $A$). Moreover, $f$ can be taken to be injective by inserting the instruction into the code of the enumerator that says "don't spit out $k$ if $k$ has already been spit out before".

Suppose $A\not= \emptyset$ and suppose $A$ is finite. Say $A=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$. Define the function $N\to N$ by sending $i$ to $x_i$ provided $i\in \{1,\dots, m\}$ and by sending all other $i$ to (for example) $x_1$. This function is total and is computable by this program: it accepts $i$, checks whether $i\in \{1,\dots, m\}$ and then either outputs $x_i$ or outputs $x_1$.

Conversely, Suppose $A$ is the image of a total computable function $f$. Let $p$ be the number of a program computing $f$. Here's how to construct an enumerator for $A$: for each $n=0,1,2,\dots$, run $\phi_p(n)$, print the output, replace $n$ with $n+1$, and repeat. This works for finite or infinite $A$. (Maybe not for empty $A$.)

Comment: Assuming that is the definition of [computably enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) that you are intended to use, your proof has all the right ideas. (I am more used to taking the first of the two definitions offered on that Wikipedia page as the actual definition and deriving the second one.) The image of a total computable function cannot be empty, but that doesn't matter given what you are trying to prove.